# Entity Framework mapping between multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I am trying to get the correct mapping between 4 tables.

MainTables

Class(Id, ClassName)

Course(Id, CourseName)

Student(Id, StudentName)

Relationship tables

ClassCourse(Id, ClassId, CourseId)

ClassCourseStudent(ClassCourseId, StudentId)

Class to Course has Many to Many mapping. So we use a relationship table ClassCourse to store the relationship

Student has one to Many mapping with ClassCourse.

So my question is how can I do the mapping for Student and ClassCourse

My code is

```
public class Class
(
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ClassName {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get;set;}
)

public class Course
(
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string CourseName {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}
)

public class Student
(
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string StudentName {get;set;}
)
modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().ToTable("Class");
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");

modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().HasMany(c => c.Courses).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("ClassCourse") 
m.MapLeftKey("ClassId")
m.MapRightKey("CourseId")
)

modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(c => c.Students).WithMany().Map(m =>               
 m.ToTable("ClassCourseStudent") 
 m.MapLeftKey("ClassCourseId")
 m.MapRightKey("StudentId")
```

The last mapping is the one I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks about right, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel In the last mapping. It is expecting the left key to be CourseId and right key to be StudentId. But because the ClassCourseId is a primary key of ClassCourse table, it doesn't match with the CourseId, hence no records are returned. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to revisit your design. Right now you're trying to assign a composite key as foreign key, which can't be done.

What I would do is create a separate model that simply stores the course-class combination and provides a single key to reference. This will result in an extra table, but allows you to do what you want.

```
class Student {
 public int StudentId {get; set;}
}

class Class {
 public int ClassId {get; set;}
}

class Course {
 public int CourseId {get; set;}
}

class ClassCourse {
 public int ClassCourseId {get; set;}
 public int ClassId {get; set;}
 public int CourseId {get; set;}
}
```

Now every class should have a list of `ClassCourse` objects instead of `Course`, and every `Course` should have a list of `ClassCourse` objects. Now they're not directly linked together but are still connected trough an intermediate object and you can connect your `Student` objects to the primary key of `ClassCourse`.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, I thought the same of changing the design to make it work. Thanks again for the suggestion that composite key as foreign key will not work. :-)